# How can I specify the plugin language in WordPress?

Tags: plugin-development, language

I develop a plugin written in Portuguese, but WordPress repository "thinks" it's in english.

I would like to inform WordPress that my plugin was written in pt-br, even though I have no intention to translate it to any other language, since it's a service aimed only to Brazil.

How can I do that, please?

Thanks!

Comment: I usually write plugins in PHP then I'm glad to meet the first plugin written in another language ;) ok I stop to joke. I just want to ask you which modifications are you expected to see once wordpress.com take into account the language of the texts inside your plugin ?

Comment: Rs. Here's an example screenshot: https://www.lucasbustamante.com.br/uploads/u/2018/05/dia-18_16h19m29s_chrome.png (it says: This plugin is not available in Brazilian Portuguese. Help translate it)

Comment: read the following page for details about this message : https://make.wordpress.org/meta/handbook/documentation/translations/#this-plugin-is-not-properly-prepared-for-localization-%e2%80%93-help

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I don't have any intention of internationalizing it, I just want to specify the language it's written in. Couldn't find that info there